# How To Limit a masked textbox to only accept an integer between 0-11, C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, integer, range, maskedtextbox

OK, so I've been searching all over for the answer, and truthfully think I'm just googling the wrong thing. Anyway, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and making a simple winform, BMI Calculator. I have a masked text box for the user to enter inches. Currently the box is set to only accept an integer one or two digits long, but I'd also like to make this text-box only allow the user to enter a number between 0-11. Any help on how to do this would be great. 
The box looks like this:

```
    private void heightInches_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I do have the text box parsed and assign the input to a variable:

```
    inches = int.Parse(heightInches.Text);
```

And to make sure the input can't be left blank I'm using this:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(heightInches.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter An Input For Inches.");

                return; 
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But I'm looking more for a way that won't let the user enter anything bigger than 11 in the box. So for example, someone types 2 in the box they cant follow it with anymore integers as anything in the twenties would be too big, but if they type 1 the only integers they can type after 1 would be 0 or 1, either making their final input 10 or 11.

Comment: Forcing everything into the wrong box. Use a 1NumericUpDown1 and set the `Minimum` to 0 and `Maximum` to 11. Voila! Plus you get the added benefit of the user being able to use the mouse or up/down arrows to change the value.

Comment: Use right component (NumericUpDown) will be your best choice. See Ken White's Comment

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks I'm gonna go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a *NumericUpDown*, and set the *Minimum* to 0 and the *Maximum* to 11. This would also have the added benefit of allowing the user to use either the mouse or <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> as well as <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> to enter values.

Answer (score 1):

A ComboBox with 0-11 as choices seems easiest and allow keyboard input as well.

Comment: Dont know why you got downvoted for this - this seems like an resonable solution to me. Gave you a +1 to offset.

Comment: up voted, this is a good alternative too, I went with the numericUpDown but this is equally useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the handler onTextChanged

```
 private void heightInches_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) Handles heightInches.TextChanged
{
    Try {
      If(cint(yourTextBox.Text) > 11) {
         MsgBox("Larger than 11"); }
      }
   Catch {
      MsgBox("Not a Valid Integer"); }
   End Try 
}
```

Im sure my Syntax is a little off - but you should get the jist.

Comment: Ugh! This code tries to use a screwdriver to hammer a nail. There's a control designed specifically for allowing a limited range of numeric values, which also offers mouse and keyboard (up/down arrow) support out of the box. with zero code necessary - just set a couple of control properties and it's done. (Not downvoting, but it's far from the optimal solution.)

Comment: huh, I've never even heard of numeric up/down - weird ...  I will go look more into now. Thanks for the tip.